# how to design an effecient database for multi client and each having thousands of records

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

My Question related to DB design and efficiency. Probably this question have asked before but I cant find any detail info. Come to the point.

Requirement.

I have 500 Customers i.e Schools now some of the schools may have different branches say each school has 3 branches.
each branch has 8 to 10 thousands maximum students. now each student has attendance record almost about 3000 rows maximum.  500 X 3 X 8000 X 3000 = 36000000000 total records have to be searched. I need to design a database that can efficiently handle such a huge records. i mean If I query the DB to find attendance of a student for xyz branch of ABC school

What will be the ways to achive a
please guide me how to achieve this with keep in mind the following factors.

Best Db vendor that give best results.

What will be the design for this and how to make it efficient when concurrent calls will come to db from different schools i.e at same time different schools querying database. let say query is same as describe above.

what design guide line would use to achieve efficiency in terms of query optimization, db designing and optimizations for this type of db. Any Suggestions and links are welcome

Comment: Sorry, this comes across as way to broad - much like "design an implement my contract for me". Can you be more specific on what you are looking for the most help with?

Comment: 36 billion is not exactly a lot of data for even a midrange server these days. I work regularly on a 10 billion row table doing complex analysis and that runs nice on a lower end server (8 cores, 48gb memory).

Comment: Actually I am almost beginner and learning things so I Really appreciate if you guide me. I know these Days huge amount of data is handled by db servers but How? how you optimize query or db? I really Thank full to you.

Comment: This question is too broad. This sounds like a serious project, and it warrants the time you need to spend reading some books before you begin.

Comment: A complete Book reading take lot of time although I appreciate if you suggest one. I also Google about it but perhaps i am not giving exact keywords so i am not getting the desired results from google. I appreciate if you suggest me some links or books

Comment: @Mubasher, I understand there's a language barrier to overcome here, but it would appear that you have a level of understanding below what a project like this would require. Having said that, you can learn more. Start with "database design and optimization book", returns several promising results. Find SQL blogs on the net, but don't spend days reading them, keep them in mind for searching for specific problems, and then there's the application software and the server hardware. Hope that helps.

Comment: When it comes to the topic of database performance, I warmly recommend [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/). You should be able to read it and **understand it** in under a week, putting you in a much better position to judge what needs to be done in the actual project.

Comment: Thanks Every One for your response and valuable advice. I hope if I came across further Ambiguity you guys will help me.